# PHP Module warning

Tags: php

I ran the command php –I and I received the following warning:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: ▒=!: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20020429, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

As you can see it doesn't give me the module name, how can I discover the module name?

Modules installed

```
-bash-3.2$ php -m

Warning: PHP Startup: ▒=!: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20020429, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
gd
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
oci8
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
SQLite
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

As you can see from running the php -m I get the error again, but no insight to what module it might be.

Comment: Which modules are loaded, using phpinfo();?

Comment: I'd say that `▒=!` is the module name, whatever that is.

Comment: best bet may be to remove php and all dependencies and try re installing, it could be that you have an module installed which is not compatible with the current version of php, have you upgraded php recently?

Comment: Dave, yes I agree with your statement that there is a module installed which in not compatible with the current version of php. This is shared development box, so removing php and all dependencies is not an option. I am trying to determine the module and remove that rather than starting over.

Comment: Yes the php error log, has the same warning with no module name.